# How can I prevent CPU overflow while optimizing tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to optimize the following hyperparameters with pso for segmentation in modified Unet model.

Hyperparameters: Dropout, learning_rate, factor, min_lr

tensorflow==2.0.0

keras==2.3.1

PSO iterations number = 10

PSO Particle number = 10

10 models are running in each iteration (PSO iteration). This means a total of 100 models will run (model_1, model_2,...,model_100). But, when I go to the 2nd iteration, I get a memory overflow error on the 19th model. For the solution of this, I looked and applied similar problems on this platform, but the error did not go away. How can I avoid this memory overflow?
I also tried the following code to solve this problem (for tensorflow 1.* version compatibility).
First Soution Try:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=36,inter_op_parallelism_threads=2, allow_soft_placement=True, device_count = {'CPU': 36})
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
K.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
```

THE CODE (Current State): The code block below is run on the calculation set with 36 CPUs requested in the slurm script file.

```
def objective_function(x):
    _ = tf.Variable([1])
    context._context = None
    context._create_context()
    tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(36)
    tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(2)
    Dropoutt = x[0]
    Llearning_rate = x[1]
    Factorr = x[2]
    Mmin_lr = x[3]
    with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
        model = get_unet_mod(input_img, n_filters=16, dropout=Dropoutt, batchnorm=True)
        model_isim = model.name
        model.compile(optimizer=Adam(amsgrad=True, learning_rate=Llearning_rate), loss=jaccard_distance_loss, metrics=["accuracy", dice_coef, f1])
        Callbackss = [ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="loss",mode="min",factor=Factorr, patience=10, min_lr=Mmin_lr, verbose=0)]
        results = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, verbose=0, epochs=30, callbacks=Callbackss, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

PSO(objective_function, bounds, particle_size, iterations)
```

Error:

slurmstepd: error: step 8207716.4294967294 hit memory+swap limit at least once during execution. this may or may not result in some failure.

Comment: Your job is using more memory than you allocated to it.

Comment: Yes like that. However, I need to prevent this and make it use as much CPU as I have allocated to it. How can I do that ?
Note: I tried this in 2 ways above and failed. Is there another way?

Comment: The problem isn't in the number of resources I've allocated. No matter how many resources I use, tensorflow will always demand more from the resource I have allocated.